# How to override only component from third party library and use template(html), CSS from parent component in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

How to override only component from third party library and use template, CSS from parent component  in Angular 4?

1) Is it mandatory to override template and CSS, while overriding third party library in Angular?

2) Is it not mandatory then give example like how to override?

I'm using this lib ngx-carousel in my angular 4 and i want override on particular method from the library component and do not want to override html and css?

Comment: That's usually what events are for. If you want to change the component behavior you would only subscribe to events and change what they do.

Comment: can you give example(or link) for that?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) can do what you want.

In my case, I wanted to subclass a component, without overriding the html template.
A normal subclass requires a new html template, but I wanted to keep the original html template.

I used the Host and Self directives from angular core to re-assign certain methods of the class.
The effect is similar to creating a subclass.

Procedure:

- Create a file with the following code. I modified primeng's calendar component, but of course, you can modify another component.
- Add the class (MyCalendar, in this example) to the declarations section in app.module.ts, the same as any other component.
- Add the directive as an html attribute where you use the component: `<p-calendar myCalendar ...></...>`

Sample code (This uses Angular 11. Is Angular 4 still supported?)

```
import {Directive, Host, Optional, Self} from "@angular/core";
import {Calendar} from "primeng/calendar";
@Directive({
    selector: '[myCalendar]',
})
export class MyCalendar {
    constructor(@Host() @Self() @Optional() public hostCalendar: Calendar) {
        hostCalendar.parseValueFromString = (text: string) => {
            return doSomething1(text);
        }
        hostCalendar.formatDateTime = (date: any) => {
            return doSomething2(date);
        }
    }
}
```